# Prism user control height auto freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I use prism mvvm and it freezes when I try to display a region:

Shell.xaml

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"    
                Grid.Column="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Width="631">
        <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Name="RightRegion" 
                        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RightRegion" 
                        Width="Auto" 
                        Margin="0,0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

CSVDisplyControl.xaml

```
  <DataGrid Name="CSVRecords"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records}" 
            AutoGeneratingColumn="AutoGeneratingColumn" 
            ToolTip="See records" 
            IsReadOnly="True"   
            ColumnWidth="*" 
            AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF4F7B5" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            Width="630" 
            MinHeight="500" 
            Height="auto" />
```

If i put a specific value for height in one of the both parts it works, but if i put auto in the both places when i call requestnavigate it does not show anything and the UI freezes.

Comment: Does the UI really freeze, or is there just no content shown?

Comment: The freeze. If i click much times the application tells "not responding".